# Centos bin/mail not working

Tags: email

I have recently created CentOS 6.4 server through linode and proceeded to setup a fairly standard LAMP setup. PHP and apache running fine. Mail is not working. Testing from the command line:

```
/bin/mail -v -s "Enter Subject Line here" "me@gmail.com" < /tmp/test.txt
```

Doesn't show any errors nor does /var/log/maillog. But no email comes into my gmail account. Checked spam.

I haven't done any config related with mail at all. Do I need to? what?

also, I'm wondering if it maybe related to my hostname, which is

```
foobar.mydomain.com (FQDN)
```

But I don't have any DNS pointing at that. DNS points at:

```
dev.mydomain.com
```

Some advice on how to debug and diagnose this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a local MTA (like postfix or sendmail) installed?

Comment: Unless it is installed by default, probably no.  How to check?

Comment: rpm -q sendmail and rpm -q postfix

Comment: sendmail no... postfix: postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64

Comment: check if is started (service postfix status)

Comment: "master is stopped".  So, started.  tried again... Bingo, into gmail (spam).  Repackage your comments as an answer and I'll check.  How to keep starting on reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have any MTA installed:

```
rpm -q postfix
```

If yes, check if it is started:

```
service postfix status
```

To make it start on system startup:

```
chkconfig postfix on
```

Check with:

```
chkconfig --list postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

Since CentOS is not anything special, you have only couple of options.

1) No actual MTA such as Postfix installed and configured.

2) Some strange iptables rules preventing you from sending mail.

3) Some strange SELinux rules preventing you from sending mail.

4) You have some MTA installed, but a typo in its config.

Choose one or more of above, then start telling us more. :)

Comment: postfix is installed but I have done no configuration at all on it.  Is that it?  All the others seem unlikely, since I don't think I've touched anything that could have messed them up.

Comment: Did you check what your `/var/log/mail.log` tells you?

Comment: log didn't show anything.  Thanks for the insights.